# How do I re-use this code for multiple instances?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to set a time interval in two inputs (start time and end time). It works great, but I want to allow the user to create any number of time picker pairs. Can I send the current timepicker with tpStartSelect(this) or similar to re-use tpStartSelect/tpEndSelect for every time picker pair? If that makes any sense.

```
$('.start_time.timepicker').timepicker({
    onSelect: tpStartSelect
});
$('.end_time.timepicker').timepicker({
    onSelect: tpEndSelect
});

function tpStartSelect( time, endTimePickerInst ) {
   $('.end_time.timepicker').timepicker('option', {
       minTime: {
           hour: endTimePickerInst.hours,
           minute: endTimePickerInst.minutes
       }
   });
}

function tpEndSelect( time, startTimePickerInst ) {
   $('.start_time.timepicker').timepicker('option', {
       maxTime: {
           hour: startTimePickerInst.hours,
           minute: startTimePickerInst.minutes
       }
   });
}
```

(The actual plug-in code for timepicker() is on this page and I'm using example 4 from the bottom https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/)

Thank you!

Comment: So basically you just want the element to be anything?

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Right now I need to set $('#element').timepicker() in two places. It's ok for the first time, but inside the two functions it would be great if they could fetch the element from the first time it's given, making it easier to re-use it for multiple instances. Can I pass the element into the functions instead of re-stating it?

Comment: have it target `this`, then bind the functions.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, how do I do that?

Comment: mdn function bind

Comment: @KevinB Sorry, I still don't know how to put that in context. Thanks.

Comment: they're search terms, that take you to the documentation for function.bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ain't pretty, but this is doing what I want (row_no ticks up as the user adds more). Thanks all.

```
$('.start_time-'+row_no).timepicker({
    onSelect: tpStartSelect
});
$('.end_time-'+row_no).timepicker({
    onSelect: tpEndSelect
});

function tpStartSelect( time, endTimePickerInst ) {
   $('.end_time-'+row_no).timepicker('option', {
       minTime: {
           hour: endTimePickerInst.hours,
           minute: endTimePickerInst.minutes
       }
   });
}

function tpEndSelect( time, startTimePickerInst ) {
   $('.start_time-'+row_no).timepicker('option', {
       maxTime: {
           hour: startTimePickerInst.hours,
           minute: startTimePickerInst.minutes
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you already have the tool necessary. If every element that has a class of `timepicker` then you only need to do this once.

```
$('.timepicker').each(function(el) 
{ 
    el.timepicker({
        onSelect: tpStartSelect
    });
}
```

Comment: The first option will make them change every single .timepicker on the page. They need to be able to work independently. I can set unique elements for the "outer" .timepicker(), but it would be great if the element inside the two functions referenced the current one, not any .timepicker on the page. Makes sense? There is no way I can do something like this: `$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    onSelect: tpStartSelect(this)
});`

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Thank you! I can create multiple ones and that works, it's just the two functions() that must be referencing the current ones, not all of them.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet I don't know, maybe something like this? `function tpStartSelect( time, endTimePickerInst, element ) {
   element.timepicker(`... ?

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet more ideas? Thanks

Comment: I still dont know what you need though. You said you dont want a bunch of functions to call that method. My solution works. Do you also need access to the element in the function? That's separate.